# Unable to get Select2 to get data from my mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery-select2

I've been trying a few different methods of getting Select2 to use information from my MySQL database. Currently, it seems something has been lost in translation and it's just showing the literal name of the `array(".$title")`. The database is called `vettigevrijdag` and the table is called `article`.

My PHP snippet that is to be included in the navbar:

```
<head>
    <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="select2.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
      });
    </script>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single">
    <?php
      include('db.php');
      $stmt=$db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM article");
      $stmt->execute();
      if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
          extract($row);
          $id = $row['if'];
          $title = $row['title'];
        echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$title.'</option>';
        }
      }
    ?>
    </select>
</head>
```

My db.php file:

```
<?php

$dbhost = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$dbname = "vettigevrijdag"; /* Database name */
$dbuser = "localhost"; /* User */
$dbpassword = "123456"; /* Password */


try {
    $db_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpassword);
    $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
    //throw $th;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your username is localhost?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Are you sure that the markup is generated properly and this is really related to select2?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single">
<?php
  include('db.php');
  $stmt=$db_con->query("SELECT * FROM article")->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
  foreach($stmt as $key=>$row){

    echo "<option value=\"".$row['if']."\">".$row['title']."</option>";
  }

?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that the OP can learn from it